# The closure in $(L_2[0,1] \,, \,||\,||_{2})$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness, equicontinuity

I want to prove if this statement is either true or false but I haven't found any counter-example to prove that it's false..

> The closure in $(L_2[0,1]$$,||\,||_{2})$ of  equicontinuous family of continuous function on $[0,1]$ is a compact

If anyone could help it would be a lot appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: What about the family of constant functions?

Comment: The easiest counter-example ... thanks can you write it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is false. The family of constant functions furnishes a counterexample.

I think it is worth noting that a bounded set, $F$,  in your space is pre-compact (the closure is compact) if and only if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\int_0^1 |f(x+y)-f(y)|^2\,dy=0$ uniformly for $f\in F$. C.f. Dunford and Schwartz, *Linear Operators*, vol. 1, Theorem IV.8.20.

Comment: So, is there a counterexample with a bounded family?

Comment: An equicontinuous family of functions defined on a compact domain is uniformly equicontinuous, so a bounded counterexample is not possible.